# how to handle manytone relations in a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, many-to-one

im trying to safe the serials from various products already bought, so i made a relation between the invoice table, serials table and my products table, the relations are shown below.

[image: tables]

i already made a form to add the relations between the product_table and invoice_table with the serial_table, the form is adding the relations and the serials, but the user shouldn't be available to choose the relations between the tables, it should find the idproduct and id invoice from the purchase made and store the serials and send it to the database without the user changing it, below is the picture of my form.

[image: form]

this is the formtype from the form above

```
class serialType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
           ->add('serial','integer')
           ->add('idPedido')
           ->add('idProducto')         
           ->add('agregar serial','submit')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'sava\InventarioBundle\Entity\TblProductosSeriales'
          // 'inherit_data' => true
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sava_inventariobundle_serial';
    }
}
```

i imported my orm files with the `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import` command from the tables shown above.

this is my product orm.

```
sava\InventarioBundle\Entity\TblProductos:
    type: entity
    table: tbl_productos
    fields:
        idProduct:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            column: id_product
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    lifecycleCallbacks: {
```

}

my serial key table orm.

```
sava\InventarioBundle\Entity\TblProductosSeriales:
    type: entity
    table: tbl_productos_seriales
    fields:
        idProductoSerial:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            column: id_producto_serial
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
        serial:
            type: string
            length: 80
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
    manyToOne:
        idProduct:
            targetEntity: TblProductos
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                id_product:
                    referencedColumnName: id_product
            orphanRemoval: false
        idinvoice:
            targetEntity: TblPedidos
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                id_pedido:
                    referencedColumnName: id_invoice
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

this is my invoice orm.

```
sava\InventarioBundle\Entity\TblPedidos:
    type: entity
    table: tbl_pedidos
    fields:
        idinvoice:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            column: id_invoice
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the user to be able to choose the relation why are you adding them to the form ? You can set them server side, in the controller :

so :

1. get the data of your form
2. query the database with the id from your form to get the two other ones
3. hydrate the object ( formObject->setStuff($id) )
4. persist

To give you an idea of what to do : for example if you have a serial and want to get your product id from it

```
  $serial = new Serial;
  $form = $this->createForm(new SerialType, $serial);  

  $request = $this->get('request');


  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $form->bind($request);
    // if form is valid
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // get the data sent from your form
        $data = $form->getData();
        $idSerial = $data->getSerial();


        // find your ids according to the serial you just got from the form
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeBundleBundle:Products'); 
        $idProduct = $repository->findBySerial($idSerial); 

        // hydrate the $serial
        $serial->setProduct($idProduct);


        $em->persist($serial);
        $em->flush();

        return ....
      }
  }
```

---

if you have the ids in your template do

```
<form role="form" 
          action="{{ path('your_route', { 'idProduct': idProduct, 'idInvoice': idInvoice }) }}"
          ...
    </form>
```

And then you can just get them in your controller like so

```
UpdateSerialAction($idProduct, $idInvoice)
{
```

and hydrate the form object with those two arguments

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ok, now I understand that what I have to do is input the id from the product and invoice tables to the serial table. However I don't see how I'm going to find the id with the serial that I supplied with the form if the relation doesn't exist in the moment. So I'm thinking, is there anyway that I can send the id or a related data from the product and invoice table? The page where you view the form, it displays the data related from the invoice and product table. How can I send this data to the controller, do I have to make another form or do I use the same serial form.

Comment: so i guess you have the product id and the invoice id in your twig template where the form is displayed?